# C# Dev Kit's Solution Explorer not showing up on VS Code on Mac

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, .net-8.0, c#-devkit

I am trying to run .NET 8 solution in VS Code for Mac (M1 chip).
VS Code version: 1.87.1 (Universal)

I installed C# Dev Kit extensions and signed in to my MS account.
I tried to install various versions of .NET 8 x64, but they didn't install so I installed Arm64 and that got installed:

```
6.0.404 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
7.0.101 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
8.0.201 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
```

When I open the solution in VS Code, the Solution Explorer does not show up at all.

Once opened VS Code shows a message:

> Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.LanguageServer client: couldn't create
> connection to server.

And the log in terminal says:

> Failed to find dotnet info from path, falling back to acquire runtime
> via ms-dotnettools.vscode-dotnet-runtime The architecture of the .NET
> runtime (arm64) does not match the architecture of the extension
> (x64). Dotnet path: /Users/mylap/Library/Application
> Support/Code/User/globalStorage/ms-dotnettools.vscode-dotnet-runtime/.dotnet/7.0.16~arm64/dotnet
> Activating C# + C# Dev Kit + C# IntelliCode... waiting for named pipe
> information from server... [stderr] Unhandled exception.
> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly
> 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.LanguageServer, Version=4.10.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. [Error - 14:12:54]
> Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.LanguageServer client: couldn't create
> connection to server. Error: Timeout. Named pipe information not
> received from server.     at q.
> (/Users/mylap/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-2.15.30-darwin-x64/dist/extension.js:2:1290803)
> at Generator.next ()     at s
> (/Users/mylap/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-2.15.30-darwin-x64/dist/extension.js:2:1280740)

The solution builds and runs but I am not able to manage the dependencies and overall see the Solution Explorer.

I tried to re-launch VS Code so the env variables could rebuild but with no effect.

Same happens if I create a new solution.

How to resolve it?